# QM: operators like $\hat{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \hat{{\mathbf{p}}}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

How would we treat an operator of the form $ \hat{\mathbf{A}} \propto \hat{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \hat{{\mathbf{p}}} $ ?

Would it have eigenstates that are also eigenfunctions of position and/or momentum?

**EDIT**:

I am interested in knowing if there exists a common set of eigenstates of both r and p, which normally would not commute

Comment: Have you looked at its commutator with position/momentum for your latter question? And what about its "treatment" is unclear to you - it's just another operator!

Comment: I am interested in knowing if there exists a common set of eigenstates of both $r$ and $p$, which normally would not commute

Comment: Comment to the last question (v3): If two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ have a common basis of eigenvectors, it means that they can be diagonalized simultaneously, and commute $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0$. See also e.g. [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6258/11127) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142548/2451) SE posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep the order when expanding the inner product you get terms of the form $x^ip_i$ which are not self-adjoint, due to the fact that $x^i$ doesn't commute with $p_i$. Hence the spectrum of such operator won't lie in $\mathbb R$, nor there is any hope in finding simultaneous eigenstates for both $x^i$ and $p_i$.

Expression like this are usually quantised by symmetrization: some people would simply write
$$\widehat{\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf p} = \frac12(\hat{\mathbf r}\cdot\hat{\mathbf p} + \hat{\mathbf p}\cdot\hat{\mathbf r})$$
which is now self-adjoint.

Comment: But now you've obtained an operator, which, although Hermitian, still has high chances of being rubbish for actual problem involving that classical observable...

Comment: I don't think this is really a problem, as expressions like this don't usually occur in many relevant situations